# Why my ironpython prg is not running outside of VS13?

Tags: visual-studio, scheduled-tasks, ironpython

I'll try to explain my problem...

I have a small program-script i wrote in Ironpython 2.7 with VS13. It access some LAN router to make some changes to the configurations then reboot them.

If i run it in VS13, debug or else, it works flawlessly. As soon as i try to schedule it and:

- compile and then run the Exe 
  or
- run it from the CL

it fails. details below.

When running compiled exe.

> Application: MaxRouter.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException Stack: at
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
>   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run8[[System._*Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.*_Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System._*Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.*_Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System._*Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.*_Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System._*Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.*_Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System._*Canon, System.*_Canon,
>   System._*Canon, System.*_Canon, System._*Canon, System.*_Canon,
>   System._*Canon, Int32) at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute7[[System.*_Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System._*Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.*_Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System._*Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.*_Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System._*Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.*_Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,
>   System._*Canon, System.*_Canon, System._*Canon, System.*_Canon,
>   System._*Canon, System.*_Canon, Int32) at
>   IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext,
>   System.String, IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple, Int32) at
>   IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.InitializeModuleEx(System.Reflection.Assembly,
>   System.String, System.String[], Boolean) at PythonMain.Main()

CL run, as a batch running ipy.exe>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Z:\My Documents\Personal\VS Proj\MaxRoutSpeed\MaxRoutSpeed\MaxRouter.py"
    , line 1001, in <module>
      File "Z:\My Documents\Personal\VS Proj\MaxRoutSpeed\MaxRoutSpeed\MaxRouter.py"
    , line 145, in main
      File "Z:\My Documents\Personal\VS Proj\MaxRoutSpeed\MaxRoutSpeed\MaxRouter.py"
    , line 200, in WorkerThread
    SystemError: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I tried to schedule it under my user, SYSTEM and NW Service, always with no joy.

**EDIT**
I think the issue maybe here:

```
auth = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(cLogin + ":" + cPW))
```

and then

```
webReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth)
```

Using Fiddler i noticed that the answer when logging in if I run via VS is:

```
Decoded Username:Password= myrealuser:myrealpw
```

while running as interactive is:

```
Decoded Username:Password= myrealuser:x
```

So, failing.

Why ?

---

thanks for any suggestions,

M

Comment: "it fails." : your should give more details. how does it fail? Is there an error message?

Comment: You are right, needs more info. The error is added.

Comment: Are you running visual studio as an administrator perhaps?

Comment: @Tewr, no... I am ana dmin on my machine. The Owner of the .py folder is Admin.

Comment: It may be related to the Login into the Router. Looks like it is failing (unauthorized) when run from outside VS... Possible?